# Does this cause undefined behavior or a memory leak?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, memory-leaks

We have a simple class, which allocates memory for a pointer using placement new and then constructs values in place. All good (I hope).

The point of interest is the move constructor. When I swap the pointers between the two objects (let's call them A and B, A is constructed from B), the pointer in A is now the owning pointer and the pointer in B is not an owning pointer. So then the destructor in A will deal with the clean up, but the destructor in B will choke because it will try to delete a non owning pointer (not allocated with new). I fixed that by adding an if statement to check if the size is zero (indicating not yet created object).

Yet when I compile and run this, the console just freezes. I can't seem to find the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

using std::size_t;

template<typename T>
class foo
{
private:
    T* p = nullptr;
    size_t sz = 0;

public:
    foo(T* first, T* last)
        : p(nullptr), sz(static_cast<size_t>(last - first))
    {
        p = static_cast<T*>(::operator new(sz * sizeof(T)));

        for (size_t i = 0; first != last; ++first, ++i) {
            ::new(static_cast<void*>(&p[i])) T(*first);
        }
    }

    foo(foo&& rhs) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(p, rhs.p);
        std::swap(sz, rhs.sz);
    }

    ~foo()
    {
        if (sz != 0)
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
                (&p[i])->~T();
            }
            ::operator delete(static_cast<void*>(p));
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    int arr[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    foo<int> f(arr, arr + 5);
    foo<int> f2 = std::move(f);
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuilt? If that doesn't work, trying restarting it.

Works good for me.

Comment: @NonCreature0714 I'm compiling with Clang using `clang++ -std=c++1z -O0 -pedantic main.cpp`. It crashes at program termination if I use `-O0`, but doesn't with `-O2` optimization. Weird...

Comment: That is strange - I don't know what constraints you're working with in your development environment, but if you're able, you could give Eclipse a go. Good IDE that's free and supports nearly all OS. It might give you more meaningful debugging.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit UB is when dragons come out of your nostrils.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Exactly, you never know what happens with UB. And wow I just noticed that. Thanks! Fixed.

Comment: This sounds like a compiler bug with NSDMIs to me. As if the move constructor isn't triggering them for some reason, rendering their values unspecified and since you're swapping them into `f` you're nuking the well-definedness of its destructor? Perhaps your debugger can shed some light. Also you should be crystal clear in your question as to your platform, compiler (name and version), switches etc.

Comment: _"the destructor in B will choke because it will try to delete a non owning pointer (not allocated with new)"_ No, it'll be a `nullptr` (at least in theory) making it perfectly safe. The conditional in the destructor shouldn't be necessary (though it's quite a good idea for clarity, if nothing else).

Comment: @NonCreature0714: Clang has a perfectly good debugger. What IDE (if any) you use with it isn't really relevant.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously broken (exception safety issues in the constructor aside).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Gotcha - Switching from Xcode to CLion and/or Eclipse saved me a lot of similar compiler/debugger headaches with C++. I've zero familiarity with clang++.

Comment: @NonCreature0714: Again, both are IDEs. I'll grant you, debugger integration is a thing. But if you were struggling with compilers and switching IDEs solved it, then it's only because you simultaneously switched compilers too!

Comment: Why are you doing `p = static_cast<T*>(::operator new(sz * sizeof(T)));` when `p` should be `sz * sizeof(T*)` since it's an array of pointers, not an array of the objects themselves. If `sizeof(T)` is less than `sizeof(T*)` - which is very plausible, you won't have enough memory for the pointers.

Comment: @Olipro `int**` would be an array of `int*`'s, while `int*` is just an array of `int`'s. To be more precise they're not actual arrays, but just pointers.

Comment: @DeiDei Sorry, that's correct, I misread the code. Although on a side-note `&p[i]` would probably be more simply represented as `p+i`